# Qt: Modal from a modal (Mac)

Tags: qt

I have a Qt modal dialog (a complex form) that needs to itself pop up a modal dialog (a `QMessageBox` with `setModal(true)`). This modal should be on top of the parent modal form, and prevent interaction.

This all works swimmingly up to a point - the second modal appears, and prevents interaction with the widgets in the parent. 
However, the parent form can still receive focus - that is, I can click in it, and the window receives focus (even if I can't interact with the widgets). This becomes a problem if you task away to another application at this point - when you task back the `QMessageBox` is behind the parent which has focus (and you can't interact with the parent). Basically, you have to move the parent to reveal the `QMessageBox` before dismissing it.

Is there a way to have a modal on top of a modal on prevent this problem on Mac OS with window focus and tasking away? (Not tested other OS BTW).

Example code to reproduce the problem:

### Dialog.cpp

`pushButton` is just a standard pushbutton.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

#include <QMessageBox>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Dialog::showMeAModal);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
void Dialog::showMeAModal()
{
    QMessageBox box(this);
    box.setText(tr("modal"));
    box.setModal(true);
    box.setWindowFlags(box.windowFlags() | Qt::Popup);
    box.exec();
}
```

### Dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();
public slots:
    void showMeAModal();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

### MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    Dialog dialog(&w);
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I've tried:

- Qt::Popup on the Message Box
- Changing parent to MainWindow
- Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint on Message Box

...to no avail.